# Boolean stop signal between threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

What is the simplest way to signal a background thread to stop executing?

I have used something like:

```
volatile bool Global_Stop = false;

void do_stuff() {
    while (!Global_Stop) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this?  I know for complex cases you might need "atomic" or mutexes, but for just boolean signaling this should work, right?

Comment: `volatile` is not for multi-threading. Any time you are thinking about using `volatile` with multiple threads, you are doing it wrong. `volatile` is for memory-mapped hardware I/O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this will most likely work, but only "by accident". As @idclev463035818 already wrote correctly:

> std::atomic is not for "complex cases". It is for when you need to access something from multiple threads.

So in this case you should use `atomic<bool>` instead of volatile. The fact that `volatile` has been part of that language long before the introduction of threads in C++11 should already be a strong indication that `volatile` was never designed or intended to be used for multi-threading. It is important to note that in C++ `volatile` is something fundamentally different from `volatile` in languages like Java or C# where `volatile` is in fact related to the memory model. In these languages a `volatile` variable is much like an atomic in C++.

In C++, `volatile` is used for what is often referred to as "unusual memory", where memory can be read or modified outside the current process (for example when using memory mapped I/O). `volatile` forces the compiler to execute all operations in the exact order as specified. This prevents some optimizations that would be perfectly legal for atomics, while also allowing some optimizations that are actually illegal for atomics. For example:

```
volatile int x;
         int y;
volatile int z;

x = 1;
y = 2;
z = 3;
z = 4;

...

int a = x;
int b = x;
int c = y;
int d = z;
```

In this example, there are two assignments to `z`, and two read operations on `x`. If `x` and `z` were atomics instead of volatile, the compiler would be free to see the first store as irrelevant and simply remove it. Likewise it could just reuse the value returned by the first load of x, effectively generate code like `int b = a`. But since `x` and `z` are volatile these optimizations are not possible. Instead, the compiler has to ensure that *all* volatile operations are executed in the *exact order* as specified, i.e., the volatile operations cannot be reordered with respect to each other. However, this does not prevent the compiler from reordering non-volatile operations. For example, the operations on `y` could freely be moved up or down - something that would not be possible if `x` and `z` were atomics. So if you were to try implementing a lock based on a volatile variable, the compiler could simply (and legally) move some code outside your critical section.

Last but not least it should be noted that marking a variable as `volatile` does not prevent it from participating in a data race. In those rare cases where you have some "unusual memory" (and therefore really require `volatile`) that is also accessed by multiple threads, you have to use volatile atomics.

Answer (score 5):

`std::atomic` is not for "complex cases". It is for when you need to access something from multiple threads. There are some myths about `volatile`, I cannot recall them, because all I remember is that `volatile` does not help when you need to access something from different threads. You need a `std::atomic<bool>`. Whether on your actual hardware accessing a `bool` is atomic does not really matter, because as far as C++ is concerned it is not.

Comment: some `volatile` myths are somewhat true ;) For example `volatile bool`  behaves as atomic on msvc compiler unless one disables the option

Comment: @bartop: IIRC `int` also behaves atomically on MSVC; it's not that strange. But this is not the language-guaranteed, interoperable with other threading constructs `atomic`. It's more "let's not break existing code from 1997" atomic.

Comment: @bartop afaik if `int` or `bool` is already atomic then using `std::atomic<int>` / `std::atomic<bool>` has almost no overhead (it doesn't use mutex or other synchronization when it isnt needed), hence there is no reason to rely on compiler specifics

Comment: easy guys, I just gave fun fact. I also believe `std::atomic` should be always used for portability

Answer (score 3):

Yes there's a problem: that's not guaranteed to work in C++. But it's very simple to fix, so long as you're on at least C++11: use [`std::atomic<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) instead, like this:

```
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<bool> Global_Stop = false;

void do_stuff() {
    while (!Global_Stop) {
        //...
    }
}
```

One problem is that the compiler is allowed to reorder memory accesses, so long as it can prove that it won't change the effect of the program:

```
int foo() {
    int i = 1;
    int j = 2;
    ++i;
    ++j;
    return i + j;
}
```

Here the compiler is allowed to increment `j` before `i` because it clearly won't change the effect of the program. In fact it can optimise the whole thing away into `return 5;`. So what counts as "won't change the effect of the program?" The answer is long and complex and I don't pretend to understand them all, but one part of it is that the compiler only has to worry about threads in certain contexts. If `i` and `j` were global variables instead of local variables, it could still reverse `++i` and `++j` because it's allowed to assume there's only one thread accessing them *unless you use certain thread primatives* (such as a `mutex`).

Now when it comes to code like this:

```
while (!Global_Stop) {
    //...
}
```

If it can prove the code hidden in the comment doesn't touch the `Global_Stop`, and there are no thread primatives such as a mutex, it can happily optimise it to:

```
if (!Global_Stop) {
    while (true) {
        //...
    }
}
```

If it can prove that `Global_Stop` is `false` at the start then it can even remove the `if` check!

Actually things are even worse than this, at least in theory. You see, if a thread is in the process of writing to a variable when another thread accesses it then only part of that write might be observed, giving you a totally different value (e.g. you update `i` from `3` to `4` and the other thread reads `7`). Admittedly that is unlikely with a `bool`. But the standard is even more broader than this: this situation is *undefined behaviour*, so it could even crash your program or have some other weird unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Isn't that what "volatile" is for -- to prevent the compiler from proving/assuming the value doesn't change?

Comment: @CaptainCodeman: Correct. Even a simple read of a`volatile` variable can affect not just other threads, but even things outside the current program. That's why the compiler may not do such optimizations.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman You're right, and in fact some of what I said about optimising away accesses doesn't apply to volatile variables e.g. optimising the `while` into an `if`. However, those accesses still aren't guaranteed to be synchronised across threads - I know that seems weird but it's how the standard is written (before C++11 it didn't say anything about threads at all so when they added the wording they chose to make new abstractions rather than make use of old ones). I'm stepping outside of what I solidly understand, but while it seems contradictory you can't use `volatile` for this.